# Kotlin: Can I create a variable through readLine function?

Tags: kotlin, if-statement, user-interface, variables, readline

For example, user will input "hamis" with readLine(), and kotlin will create mutable var named hamis. I was thinking of limited if function, but that's unpractical.

Comment: Oh I see.  You are trying to create a new variable named with the string you typed in.  You could do this with a map (similar to python dict) in which that variable name can be used as the key, and you can assign values to that map entry.

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of us is confused here :-)

[`readLine()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html) is simply a function that returns a String<sup>*</sup>.

You're free to assign it to a variable if you want, e.g.:

```
var input = readLine()
```

(That's the usual way of using it, though you could instead use it directly in an expression of any kind.)

So if the user types `hamis`, then that's what `readLine()` will return, and what `input` will be set to.

And because it's a `var`, you could later set it to something else.

Is that what you're asking?  I'm not sure where an `if` would come into it…

(Variable names must be known at compile time, so you can't create a variable with a name that's entered at runtime.  How would you refer to it in the rest of your program?)

Perhaps it would help if you told us some of the big picture about what you're trying to achieve here…?

---

<sup>(* Technically, it returns a nullable String; it can return null if it's redirected from a file, and reaches the end of the file; or if it's reading from the keyboard and you type the end-of-file character, which is Ctrl+D on Mac and Unix.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks but I was thinking, that if an user will input "hamis" then there will be mutable var "hamis" with value that will be assigned later (maybe in another readLine), and not val input = "hamis". Literally a function that will program itself.